# SQL Missing Select statement - Update Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this SQL code for Oracle. I am trying to update the database based on a subquery.

```
with T as 
(SELECT "Folder Name", SUM("Session Length") as "Folder Length" 
 FROM "SESSIONUSAGE" 
 GROUP BY "Folder Name")
UPDATE FolderUsage SET ("Folder Length") = 
(SELECT "Folder Length" FROM T
    WHERE (FolderUsage."Folder Name" = T."Folder Name")
```

I needed the spaces as that's how I found the database. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And what happens when you run the query?

Comment: it's missing a ")" at the end but it will update all folder length

Answer (score 3):

The proper syntax is

```
update FolderUsage
  set "Folder Length" =
    ( 
       with T as ( <aggregate SELECT statement defining T goes here> )
       select "Folder Length" from T where ........
    )
```

The `WITH` clause belongs with the `SELECT` statement of which it is a subquery; the `WITH` clause does NOT go above the `UPDATE` clause!

However, in this case you may do better with the `MERGE` statement:

```
merge into FolderUsage F
  using ( <aggregate SELECT statement defining T goes here> ) T
    on (F."Folder Name" = T."Folder Name")
when matched then update set "Folder Length" = T."Folder Length"
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, your parentheses don't balance:

```
with T as (
      SELECT "Folder Name", SUM("Session Length") as "Folder Length" 
      FROM "SESSIONUSAGE" 
      GROUP BY "Folder Name"
    )
UPDATE FolderUsage
    SET "Folder Length" = (SELECT "Folder Length"
                           FROM T
                           WHERE FolderUsage."Folder Name" = T."Folder Name"
                          );
```

But, Oracle still won't accept this.  So, instead:

```
UPDATE FolderUsage
    SET "Folder Length" = (SELECT SUM(su."Session Length")
                           FROM "SESSIONUSAGE" su
                           WHERE FolderUsage."Folder Name" = su."Folder Name"
                          );
```

I think this is simpler anyway.